# Alterar propriedades de um componente contido em um módulo do sistema

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3

Estou modulando um sistema desenvolvido em Delphi XE3. Um dos meus módulos denomidados `Default` possui um `dmDados` com uma conexão. Na minha aplicação principal, no `onShow` do meu Form principal estou carregando o módulo e tentando desconectar o meu componente de conexão:

```
LoadPackage('modules/Default.bpl');
dm_Connection.ZConnection.Disconnect;
```

Mas estou recebendo uma mensagem de *Access Violation*. Acredito que não estou fazendo da maneira correta. Como devo fazer?

Comment: Possivelmente quando você carrega a bpl, o seu  datamodule ainda não esteja carregado. se vc fizer `dm_Connection := TdmDados.Create(Application);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que instancia os *forms* e *datamodules* em uma aplicação Delphi é o código contido no corpo do programa principal (arquivo **.DPR**). O Delphi coloca este código de forma automática cada vez que um novo *form* ou *datamodule* é adicionado ao projeto, quando se trata de um projeto para gerar um **.EXE**.

Quando se trata de uma projeto de *package* no entanto, tal código não é automaticamente incluído.

Será necessário que você instancie manualmente todos os objetos que desejar dentro de um *package*. Isso é especialmente verdade quando o programador decide fazer a carga do *runtime package* manualmente, como parece que é o que você está fazendo (chamando `LoadPackage`).

Uma forma de pré-inicializar uma série de objetos dentro do package é escolher uma unit e adicionar o código para a criação das instância no `initialization` desta *unit*.

Quando um *package* é carregado, o código existente dentro da sessão `initialization` de todas as *units* é executado em alguma ordem sem controle. Quando o *package* é descarregado, o código existente dentro das sessões `finalization` de todas as *units* é executado, novamente sem uma garantia de ordem.

Recomendo a leitura um [artigo interessante](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/27178) que pode ser de boa valia para você. Este artigo faz uma comparação entre o uso de DLLs e *packages* e mostra como estes últimos são mais fáceis e diretos, pois todos os tipos declarados dentro dele ficam disponíveis para uso tão logo o *package* seja carregado.

Comment: Só uma dúvida, para pré-inicializar um objeto é apenas `Application.CreateForm(TDF001a, DF001a);`, por exemplo?

Comment: @ThiagoThaison: o método `Application.CreateForm` é indicado para a criação de *forms*, *datamodules*, *frames* e seus descendentes (mas funciona com qualquer componente). Para instanciar uma classe que não seja um destes (uma instância de `TUsuario`, por exemplo) usa-se o *constructor* diretamente. Até mesmo para *forms* se poderia usar o *constructor* diretamente. O que o método em questão faz é instanciar e atribuir para a variável passada como segundo parâmetro.